# Open Interval in subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$.  If there exists an open interval contained in $X$, then $\# X = \# \Bbb R$.

Comment: Well, if you take away a countable amount of points from $\Bbb R$, the cardinality doesn't change: any idea of a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ that has points in every possible interval?

Comment: Is there an elegant way to prove the falsehood of the converse using the fact that there is a rational number in every open interval

Comment: Exactly! Take them away and you've broken every interval up.

Comment: But then how does $\# Y = \#R$, I'm sorry, I'm really confused

Comment: Well, if removing a countable set gave you a countable set, then the union of those two countable sets would be more than countable... Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Ohh I got the converse now, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a short way to prove the first part??

Answer (score 2):

For the converse just take the set of irrationals $\;Irr.:=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;$ . It has the same cardinal as the reals (why?), yet it contains no open non-trivial interval (again, why?) .

For the first part of the original question: if $\;(a,b)\subset X\;$ , then use that *any* open interval is homeomorphic to $\;(0,1)\;$ by means of the homeomorphism

$$x\mapsto\frac{x-a}{b-a}\;\;\text{(show this is a continuous bijection and find its inverse)}$$

and now, composing homeomorphisms, observe that also $\;(a,b)\sim(-\pi/2\,,\,\pi/2)\;$ , and this last is hom. with $\;\Bbb R\;$ by means of $\;f(x):=\tan x\;$ , with obvious continuous inverse...

Comment: Thanks, I got the converse, I couldn't figure out how to prove the equal cardinalities of X and R

Comment: @112358 In your first, original message, which I addresses, you said you got the first part, which is what it is written now. The second part said that the converse (i.e., if $\;|X|=|\Bbb R|\;$ then $\;X\;$ contains an open interval) is what I answered here.

Comment: I got the converse after looking at your reply, thanks! however I'm still confused about the first part, I may have made a typing error if it came across to you as if I had understood it.

Comment: @112358 I added some stuff now to my answer.